# Are there integral solutions for $(2a-1)(2^{(b+c)}-3^c )=2^b-1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Can anyone prove this assertion?  Or at least suggest a method of attack?  It has come up in my research.

There do not exist $a,b$ and $c$ such that$$
 (2a-1)(2^{(b+c)}-3^c )=2^b-1
$$where $a>0,b>1,c>1$ and $a,b,c ∈ Z$

This question came up as I was comparing 2 types of sums: $S1=x+(3/2)x+(3/2)^2x+...+(3/2)^cx, S2=y+2y+2^2y+...+2^by$ to see if they could ever equal one another, given specific constraints on the relationship between x and y - specifically that $y=2x−1$ and $x=2^c(2a−1) $

Comment: What are you studying?
What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with?
Is this question something you think should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: @Shaun It is an intermediate result I obtained while attacking the Collatz Conjecture.

Comment: I have yet to find an example when $(2^b-1)/(2^{b+c}-3^c)$ would be $\ge1$ let alone an odd positive integer. Need $3^c$ to be very close to $2^{b+c}$ for there to be a chance.

Comment: With $b,c\le100$ that ratio is $\le3/5=(2^2-1)/(2^5-3^3)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was getting similar results.  My gut feeling was that the ratio was approaching 1/2 at infinity - but have not worked it out.  I would really like to prove this assertion.  Frankly surprised that it is proving to be so stubborn.

Comment: In the tags you have Collatz listed, if I may ask how is it related?

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης It's not something I can answer simply, as the argument I'm working on is quite involved; but proving this assertion is crucial to the construction of a special type of sequence which exhibits a unique behavior under a permutation.  I know that's vague, but I can't really explain further.

Comment: @MathAllTheTime Ok I was just asking to make sure it's not a statement equivalent somehow to a weak form of the collatz conjecture that would just tire us out by being deceptively simple...

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης Good point, and I understand.  No - this is a new result.  I've worked on the conjecture for about 35 years.  Last year I finally had some insight into the problem that, for the first time, gave me some real hope.  I hit a snag (an assumption that was invalid); but I believe I may have gotten past that.  This assertion is just a small part of the technique I'm using.  It is not just a restatement of the conjecture in another form.  It is attacking one specific type of loop structure - and a simple one at that.

Comment: May be experts on [tag:diophantine-approximation] know something about how well $\log_23$ can be approximated by a rational number. That may give you a sharp enough estimate.

Comment: Your formula is the same which occurs in the analysis of the so-called "1-cycles". First disproof of existence came from R. Steiner and building on it by J. Simons and Benne de Weger(see Wikipedia). The Simons-approach is openly accessible online. I've tried to reproduce the proof (which introduces arguments from transcendental number theory) in a small essay, see http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_1cycledisproof.pdf (I hope it is correct so far)

Comment: (... continued) A very close relative to your formula appears on page 5 at the first row, and can be adapted using def (3.4) to your problem. (Of course I've different notation for the involved variables)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms This is absolutely fascinating.  I will examine your paper now, as well as Steiner, et. al.  So, if I understand correctly, this assertion has been proved to be true. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: Well, for $a=1$ this is trivial just from elementary number theory: take modulo $3$ to get that $b$ and $c$ must be odd, then take modulo $4$ to get a contradiction. Perhaps you could try induction, though I must admit I do not know how to proceed in that case.

Comment: MathOverflow copy of the question: [Are there integral solutions for $(2a-1)(2^{(b+c)}-3^c )=2^b-1$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/308977#comment769417_308977) I think that [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice about [meta-tag:cross-posting].

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Gottfried, is there a possibility I could contact you via e-mail?  Or is there a way to message using stackexchange, etc?  I would like your opinion on some of my Collatz research.  I've reached a point where I need another pair of eyes, and you appear to be very familiar with the problem.

Comment: @MathAllTheTime: helms at uni-kassel.de But I can't promise deep interaction ...

Answer (score 3):

Let me rewrite the letters for your variables due to my long-time practice.
I usually write $N$ for $c$ , $S$ for $c+b$ such that $S = \lceil N \cdot \log_2(3) \rceil$ and $B$ for $b$.
Also, to simplify I write $k$ for $2a-1$, not forgetting $k$ must be odd.

I refer also to a formula of G. Rhin, cited in J. Simons [Si,07], for a lower bound of $S \log 2 - N \log 3$ depending on $N$.

So we start with your formula, simply rewritten in notation, and then adapting for application of Rhin's inequality:
$$ \begin{array} {rl} k(2^S-3^N)&=2^B - 1 \\
 k( (2^S/3^N)-1)&=(2^B - 1)/3^N \\
 2^S/3^N &= 1 + (2^B - 1)/k/3^N 
\end{array} \tag 1$$
Logarithmizing and using the Mercatorseries on the rhs gives us
$$\small {S \ln2 - N \ln3  =  (2^B - 1)/k/3^N -1/2((2^B - 1)/k/3^N)^2+ 1/3((2^B - 1)/k/3^N)^3 \pm \ldots }$$

Cancelling of trailing small terms on the rhs gives now an ***in***-equality
$$ S \ln2 - N \ln3  \lt  (2^B - 1)/k/3^N \tag 2 $$

By G. Rhin we have due to J. Simons (formula slightly rewritten to be better memorizable):
$$\frac1{457}\frac1{N^{13.3}} \lt S \ln2 - N \ln3 \tag 3
$$
So we can conclude
$$\begin{array} {rl}  \frac1{457}\frac1{N^{13.3}} &\lt S \ln2 - N \ln3  &\lt  (2^B - 1)/k/3^N \\
\frac1{457}\frac1{N^{13.3}} &\lt  (2^B - 1)/k/3^N 
\end{array} \tag 4  $$
Now taking logarithms again gives
$$\small \begin{array} {rl}  -6.13 - 13.3 \ln N &\lt \ln (2^B - 1) - \ln k - N \ln 3 \\ 
 N \ln 3 - 13.3 \ln N &\lt 6.13 + B \ln 2 -(1/2^B + 1/2/4^B + ..) - \ln k  \\
 N \ln 3 - B \ln 2 - 13.3 \ln N &\lt 6.13  -(1/2^B + 1/2/4^B + ..) - \ln k  \\
\end{array} \tag 5$$
Here obviously the lhs is increasing with increasing $N$ while the rhs stays roughly constant *(or even decreases if you increase $k$)* so we can solve for the **equality**-condition given $N$ and $\small{B=\lceil N \cdot (\log_2 (3) -1)\rceil }$ and some assumed $k$. Say $k=3$ then at $\small {N=95.05}$ the lhs grows over the rhs.

So for $N \gt 95$ there is no solution.
The cases $N \le 95$ can be done one by one finding that no other solution exists for $N>2$

Now check for other odd $k>3$.

So you are done.

---

*Remark: I think this is easier than the Simon's exposition because I do not need to refer to the theory of continued fractions here.*

---

[Si,07]  John L Simons: On the (non)-existence of m-cycles for generalized Syracuse sequences
$ \qquad \qquad $(2007) (online update of earlier article)
[Rh,87]  G. Rhin: Aproximants de Padé et mesures d’irrationalité.
$ \qquad \qquad $Progress in Mathematics 71, (1987), pp. 155-164
$ \qquad \qquad $(Reference supplied by [Si,07])